# One Entity getting missed in iOS 8 beta 3

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, ios8, core-data-migration

Hi I had my project in AppStore,Now I have added some attributes for number of Entities in CoreData and added migration code in persistentStoreCoordinator, I am able to run successfully in 7.1.1, I updated my device to iOS 8 beta 3, Now I am not able to open my application, I have use the following code to migrate and I am getting given crash report,Please guide me how to solve this issue.

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

---

```
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample/Sample.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                          };    
// Check if we need a migration
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL error:&error];
NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [_persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectModel];
BOOL isModelCompatible = (sourceMetadata == nil) || [destinationModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
if (! isModelCompatible) {
    // We need a migration, so we set the journal_mode to DELETE
    options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}
                };
}
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
if (! persistentStore) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample"];
    NSString *sqlite = [databasePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.sqlite"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:sqlite error:nil];

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    //abort();
}
// Reinstate the WAL journal_mode
if (! isModelCompatible) {
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:persistentStore error:NULL];
    options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"WAL"}
                };
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
}
return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Crash report is:

```
Jul 21 13:15:50 Vivians-iPad-air BW - Internal[457] <Warning>: CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2114FDE-D2CD-4FC6-B6E1-90CF8F7B71FF/Documents/Boardworks/BoardWorks.sqlite options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
        "journal_mode" = DELETE;
    };
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134020.)" UserInfo=0x146c5040 {NSUnderlyingException=Can't find table for entity Agenda in database at URL file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2114FDE-D2CD-4FC6-B6E1-90CF8F7B71FF/Documents/Boardworks/BoardWorks.sqlite} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Can't find table for entity Agenda in database at URL file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2114FDE-D2CD-4FC6-B6E1-90CF8F7B71FF/Documents/Boardworks/BoardWorks.sqlite";
```

Comment: The error complains about `Agenda`. How has that changed in the data model?

Comment: Actually In this Database version, I didn't made any attribute changes  in Agenda Entity.I have done changes in other places.I am in confuse why it is showing Agenda,Do you have any idea how to debug this to find the exact place?

Comment: Hi, just to say that beta 4 is the current latest version - you may consider upgrading to this and then trying again. :)

Comment: I have tried with beta 4 also,but I have faced the same problem, I was not able to open the application.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: I have removed the  NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
        "journal_mode" = DELETE;     Then its working fine, But I think It was not exact solution :(

Comment: I suspect the error was for `Agenda` because it was first alphabetically. I am seeing the same error for my `AttachmentImage`.